# iOS In-App Purchase - Authentication Failed - There was a problem with the app store

Tags: in-app-purchase, revenuecat

Everything working fine using `RevenueCat` in Google purchasing and Apple sandbox. But in production mode (iOS 14 and Xcode 12) I got the below error on trying to make a purchase.

```
[Purchases] - DEBUG: PaymentQueue removedTransaction: agfpro3m (null) ((null) Error Domain=SKErrorDomain Code=0 "An unknown error occurred" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, NSUnderlyingError=0x282604db0 {Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 "Unhandled exception" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x282604c60 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=The verify credentials call failed., NSLocalizedDescription=Authentication Failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x2826048a0 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=0 "Authentication Failed" UserInfo=0x283c84380 (not displayed)}}}, NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred, NSLocalizedDescription=Unhandled exception}}}) {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "An unknown error occurred";
    NSUnderlyingError = "Error Domain=ASDErrorDomain Code=500 \"Unhandled exception\" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x282604c60 {Error Domain=AMSErrorDomain Code=100 \"Authentication Failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReaso
2020-10-15 09:36:10.504 [info][tid:com.facebook.react.JavaScript] [Error: There was a problem with the App Store.]
```

My app was rejected and they say the following.

We found that your in-app purchase products exhibited one or more bugs when reviewed on iPad running iOS 14.0.1 on Wi-Fi.

Specifically, there was an issue with the In app Purchase. We could not complete the purchase as we encountered a bug.

Next Steps

When validating receipts on your server, your server needs to be able to handle a production-signed app getting its receipts from Apple’s test environment. The recommended approach is for your production server to always validate receipts against the production App Store first. If validation fails with the error code "Sandbox receipt used in production," you should validate against the test environment instead.

Anyone already faced this issue?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: It's an Apple issue - there's nothing you can do unfortunately. Looks like you're not the only one: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661351

Comment: I am getting same error , did you found solution?

Answer (score 12):

This happened to my setup because the account I was trying to sign in with wasn't [registered as a Sandbox Tester](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev8b997bee1).

When testing out purchases locally, *you are always working in the sandbox*. [You must set up a sandbox tester for this to work properly.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchases_with_sandbox?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

SKError code 0 is an "Unknown" error from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skerror/code/unknown

If this happened to the reviewer during app review, there's nothing you can do on your end to resolve it. I'd try submitting the same binary or you can try explaining the situation to the reviewer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And what about code 100 error authentication failed?

Comment: I am getting same error , did you found solution?

Comment: @Oswaldo Code 100 seems to mean "you are not registered as a sandbox tester"

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug on Apple side. Mine works on iPhone SE 2(private phone), but not on iPhone 11. Both run the same iOS version.

I think Apple is unable to verify that the epost you are using, belongs to you.